# Do Google Docs notify users of suggested edits or comments if they no longer have access to the document?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

Do Google Docs notify users of suggested edits or comments if they no longer have access to the document?

E.g.

1. I have a document shared.
2. Someone makes suggested edits or comments on that document.
3. I make a copy of the document with the suggested edits and comments carried over, but do not share the new copy with the original suggested editor / commenter.
4. I accept/reject the suggested edits / comments on the document
5. Is the original author notified? How do I prevent that?